# MySQL - Sort the FIRST 3 rows only

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

My client wants a search on his wordpress website that shows the 3 first results from a specific category (premium products) and then sort the rest of the results by relevance.

It needs to be something like this:

Search: **green apple**

1. green pineapple (premium)
2. red apple (premium)
3. apple pie (premium)
4. green apple
5. big green apple
6. small green apple

I'm thinking if there is something that counts the selected rows to then create a OrderBy condition like this below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `posts` 
ORDER BY ( 
    CASE WHEN `posts.category` LIKE 'premium' AND COUNT(ROW) < 4 
        THEN 0 
        ELSE 1 
    END ), 
    `posts.post_date` DESC
```

Obs.: The rest of the search (after the first 3 premiums) needs to select literally everything that matches the search, it means that it can select premium posts as well, so I can't use "NOT LIKE `premium`".

Comment: For the sake of code-readability I'd just use 2 queries (select 3 premium producs & select all the other products).

Comment: But by selecting all the other products it could bring the same product I just selected in the previous search.

Comment: Just use the inverse `WHERE` (eg. `WHERE posts.category != 'premium'`)

Comment: The "second search" needs to select literally everything that matches the search query, so it can also have premium posts in it. I can't use "LIKE NOT".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `UNION` query to select 3 premium products and then the rest:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ((SELECT 1 AS premium, posts.* 
       FROM posts
       WHERE `posts.category` LIKE 'premium'
       ORDER BY post_date_desc
       LIMIT 3)
      UNION
      (SELECT 0 AS premium, posts.*
       FROM posts)
     ) p
GROUP BY p.ID
ORDER BY premium DESC, `p.post_date` DESC
```

`UNION` by default removes duplicates so it will prevent the same post repeating in the list.

Comment: I tried that, but the problem is that he wants to have premium posts in the rest of the search as well, I will update my question based on it...

Comment: @RaySantos you can just remove the `posts.category NOT LIKE 'premium'` condition from the second select then.

Comment: Well, but if I order the UNION of these 2 selections by premium first and the second selection got more premiums, then it will show all the premiums first, I mean more than 3, am I right?

Comment: No, it will only show the premiums from the first query first, as the others (even if they are premium) will have their `premium` value set to 0.

Comment: Oh, now I got it, I will test it right now and then I'll mark your answer as the right one, thanks for that!

Comment: Hey @Nick, there's one thing missed, I just found out that to avoid duplications I need to add a `GROUP BY p.ID` after the UNION.

Comment: @RaySantos ah yes that is because of adding the `premium` field prevents there being a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

You could just `UNION` two queries, like:

```
(SELECT p.*, 1 is_premium FROM posts p WHERE category = 'premium' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 3)
UNION
(SELECT p.*, category = 'premium' FROM posts)
ORDER BY is_premium, post_date DESC
```

The first query selects the 3 most recent premium `posts`. The second query selects all posts. `UNION` takes care of removing duplicates accross queries. The outer query puts premium posts first, and orders by descending date.